# Elasticsearch cluster health intermittently flaps between 'GREEN' and 'YELLOW'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We are running a 7 node cluster with "ZERO" replicas, like this:

```
{
"cluster_name": "my_cluster",
"status": "green",
"timed_out": false,
"number_of_nodes": 7,
"number_of_data_nodes": 7,
"active_primary_shards": 3325,
"active_shards": 3325,
"relocating_shards": 0,
"initializing_shards": 0,
"unassigned_shards": 0,
"delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
"active_shards_percent_as_number": 100.0
}
```

elasticsearch cluster state changes from "Green" to "Yellow" intermittently. The other interesting thing I noticed was during this intermittent cluster state changes, there is shard initializing taking place, which correlates with the cluster state changes. Is this due to the cluster running with "ZERO" replicas?
What could cause the above behavior ?

Comment: No, I dont believe it has anything to do with 0 replicas. We run a fairly large cluster 4 TB with 0 replicas and it works just fine. How frequently does the cluster state change ? Which version of ES is this ? Check if your cluster has enough resources specifically heap memory etc. Check logs to see if they help shed any light on whats happening, turning on DEBUG logging may help. Also post cluster health output when cluster state is yellow.

Comment: You can also use `http://IP_MASTER:9200/_cat/allocation?v` which tell you how many shards are unallocated.
Your problem can be also slow network connection between nodes or slow HHD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.find that indices with

```
http://IP_MASTER:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

2.find the node that has the shard of that indices is going assign and unassigned.

```
http://IP_MASTER:9200/_cat/shards?v
```

3. restart service elasticsearch on that node
4. if problem exist you have two option.

A. lucene check index (just check that shard)

```
java -cp lucene-core*.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene… org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /mnt/nas/elasticsearch/graylog-production/nodes/0/indices/graylog_92/0/index/ -verbose -exorcise
```

if it say doesn't find the segment, try to find and cd on that path and run the command.

B. elasticsearch fix index (it check all index and is very slow)

```
index.shard.check_on_startup: fix
```

you should set this config on elasticsearch.yml of that node.